# SSMS Import-Export Settings Options Question

Tags: ssms

Hopefully this is a simple question, but it's vexing me.   When I use the Export Settings wizard in SQL Server Management Studio (v18.4) it presents options that I don't recognize from the Tools|Options window.   These are numeric options, like, #3600, #2018, #2001, etc.

If I don't uncheck all of them before I export, I get a slew of errors.

> Your settings were exported, but there were some errors.
>   Error 1:  Failed to export settings for '#20116' [code 6714]
>   Error 2:  Failed to export settings for '#100' [code 6714]
>   Error 3:  Failed to export settings for '#1010' [code 6714]
>   Error 4:  Failed to export settings for '#1001' [code 6714]
>   Error 5:  Failed to export settings for 'Start Page' [code 922]
>   Error 6:  Failed to export settings for '#20133' [code 844]
>   Error 7:  Failed to export settings for '1050' [code 844]
>   Error 8:  Failed to export settings for '#3600' [code 844]
>   Error 9:  Failed to export settings for '2015' [code 844]
>   Error 10:  Failed to export settings for '2001' [code 844]
>   Error 11:  Failed to export settings for '2011' [code 844]
>   Error 12:  Failed to export settings for '2012' [code 844]
>   Error 13:  Failed to export settings for '2013' [code 844]

But, the first line implies that, maybe I'm ok.   But, if I try to import the file just I just exported, I get...

> Your settings were imported, but there were some errors.
>   Error 1:  An error occurred while importing settings for 'Start Page' [code 5302].
>   Error 2:  An error occurred while importing settings for '#20116' [code 5297].
>   Error 3:  An error occurred while importing settings for '#100' [code 5297].
>   Error 4:  An error occurred while importing settings for '#1010' [code 5297].
>   Error 5:  An error occurred while importing settings for '#1001' [code 5297].

More importantly, some of the keyboard shortcuts present when I exported, are not reloaded with the import.

[SSMS Export Wizard Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTol3.png)

My question is two-part.

1) What are these options? 
2) Is there an easy/easier way for me to bypass/remove them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like these errors could be due to settings left over from an older version of SSMS.

Reseting your settings might resolve the errors. [See this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/925a3b45-7bad-4b86-9f8d-fca95112ea6d/export-settings-error-failed-to-export-settings-for-2015-code-7371?forum=visualstudiogeneral) for more info.